# How to run .sh script with keybind

Tags: xfce, shortcut-keys

I have small script that makes screenshot of selected area and then updates it on imgur

```
function uploadImage {
    curl -s -F "image=@$1" -F "key=xxx" https://imgur.com/api/upload.xml | grep -E -o "<original_image>(.)*</original_image>"  grep -E -o "http://i.imgur.com/[^<]*"
}

notify-send "Select screenshot area"
FILENAME=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y_%T")".png"
scrot -s $FILENAME 
uploadImage $FILENAME | xclip -selection c
notify-send "Screenshot $FILENAME uploaded. Link copied to clipboard."
```

i placed it in $home/screenshots/ directory. Everything works fine when i run it from terminal

```
./screenshot.sh
```

but when i try to bind it to key using Default XFCE keybinder with command

```
bash /path/to/file/screenshot.sh
```

then it doesn't work. After pressing selected key, I get first norification, and second just moment after. It doesn't make any screenshot, it doesn't even wait for selection. How can i fix it?

Comment: Don't you need to add `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the file?

Comment: i'm not really sure, but i think # is just comment and #!/bin/bash is just information for user. Anyway, i will check it later :)

Comment: Oh no, that is not a simple comment. You should have noticed the *exclamation mark* after the *comment mark* and a *path*. That is commonly known as [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). For more information, [here is a SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7061460/1505348)

Comment: Bash interprets it as a comment, but the kernel interprets it specially.

Comment: We could be more helpful if we had the output of the script. Give the keybinder the command `/path/to/file/screenshot.sh >$HOME/output.log 2>&1` (which will redirect the standard output and the error output of the script to a file).

Comment: Anyway, adding `#!/bin/bash` didn't help.
`/home/smiechowy/screenshots/screenshot.sh >$HOME/output.log 2>&1` doesn't even create file (when called from keybind, when i call it from terminal it works, it creates file but it's empty).

Comment: That's unexpected. Does this create the file?: `/path/to/file/screenshot.sh 2>&1 | tee $HOME/output.log` Please write @ignis in your reply, so I am notified when you reply.

Comment: If `tee` does not work, please write `exec > $HOME/otuput.log 2>&1` at the beginning of the script (as a new line just after the hashbang), and invoke the script from the keybinder as `bash /path/to/file/screenshot.sh`

Comment: @ignis, `tee` didn't work. Second method gave me this `giblib error: couldn't grab keyboard:Resource temporarily unavailable` in output file.

Comment: okay, i found (not best) solution, adding `sleep 0.2` in the beginning of the script helps :)

Comment: @smiechowy Please write it into an answer, and mark it as accepted. This will give visibility to the solution, which would otherwise be lost among the comments. I think it will also give you a few points. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, following ignis advise, I guess i found solution, adding `sleep 0.2` at the beginning of script does the trick :)