# Can't assign script that takes control of mouse to shortcut

Tags: command-line, 18.04, shortcut-keys, colors, cursor

## Background

I have a small script that uses [xcolor](https://github.com/Soft/xcolor) to pick a color from the screen and paste it to the clipboard ([xclip](https://github.com/astrand/xclip)).

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

color=$(xcolor)
echo "$color" | xclip -sel clip
notify-send "$color copied to the clipboard"
```

## Problem

The script works when invoked from the terminal. However, **I have not been able to make it work as a keybinding**. After setting a keybinding to the script (*Settings > Devices > Keyboard*), pressing it does not change the cursor to a color-picker as in the CLI command; it just finish automatically, sending the notification with `$color` as an empty variable.

## Technical details

Ubuntu 18.04.4, GNOME 3.28.4, Kernel 5.3.

### Edit

I set the Keybinding via GUI of Ubuntu Settings (in GNOME), *Settings > Devices > Keyboard*:

[Screenshot of keybinding settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve7U4.png)

The script has execute permission; using `bash /home/jorge/usrc/color-clip` or `dash /home/jorge/usrc/color-clip` as **Command** produces the same wrong behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run .sh script with keybind](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319400/how-to-run-sh-script-with-keybind).  You told us that your method to set a keybind didn't work, but you didn't tell us what method are you using.  Please add that info in an [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1250707/edit), if this other question doesn't solve your issue

Comment: @Nmath No, although it looks similar to my issue, adding sleep 0.2 at the beginning of the script does not solve the problem. I have also tried putting the sleep command on different places with different values. Not that I understand why the sleep command would solve it. Maybe I haven't been clear, I set the keybinding using the GUI at _Settings > Devices > Keyboard_, I'll add an edit on that.

Comment: It seems like the question has been marked as a duplicate. Please, if someone was able to solve this issue by using this `sleep` solution on their machine, could you provide the script and/or the steps to follow? @Eliah

Comment: @carrasco Thanks for the updated info. I've reopened this. I probably closed it too hastily--I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Change the ```xcolor``` to ```xcolor 2>some_log_file``` to see the errors for xcolor. Have you added the location of xcolor in your ```$PATH```? I think that might be the problem. Maybe because of the environment variables of programs that Gnome executes via a shortcut. I can successfully run your script and I get the results in my clipboard in KDE plasma 5.19 . So maybe the Gnome shell cannot find the **xcolor** binary since all other lines of your script look fine in your system. You can also try moving the **xcolor** to ```/usr/bin/```.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Using the full path in the script worked! `xcolor` was installed with [cargo](https://github.com/Soft/xcolor#using-cargo) and it is in the PATH on my shell  just because of my `.bashrc`, but it is not accessible by GNOME. Can you post that as a solution or should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem might be caused by the environment variables which are defined before the Gnome-shell executes the program you've assigned a shortcut to. So you have two options :

- Using the full path of the binary instead of just `xcolor`
- Adding the `xcolor` to the list of system binaries by copy-pasting it to `/usr/bin`